# How to use keyboard shortcut to select checkboxes in macOS

Tags: macos, mac

I am trying to find the shortcut to be able to select the items on checkboxes in macOS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. There is no keyboard shortcut to select a specific checkbox, but you can use Tab to navigate through controls until the checkbox has focus and press Space to select it. You may need to enable full keyboard access in System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard.